# Sharing Dropbox folder, friends don't have enough space, but still can't see contents from website

Tags: dropbox

I created a shared folder and uploaded a lot of files - more than 2.5 gigabytes. Some people that I invited to share that folder told me they got a message that says they cannot accept the invitation because they don't have enough space.

I do realize that the folder is very heavy, but why can't they see it on the website? I understand why they can't see it on their own computer if they have only 2 gigabytes of space, but it shouldn't be a problem on the website.

Answer (score 2):

The space limitation is due to their allowed storage with Dropbox, not space available on their hard drive. They would probably need to upgrade to Dropbox Pro to get additional storage space in order to access your folder.